# Outputing time once in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make the program output the time it took to complete `fib(n)` but during the time it's calculating, it continuously posts minute amounts of time. How do I get the program to just output the time once. Here if my program:

```
import time

def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        start_time = time.time()
        answer = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
        end_time = time.time()
        total_time = end_time - start_time
        print(total_time)
        return answer
```

Comment: Your code is not complete – it does not call the function anywhere. As the time gets printed inside the recursive function, that's what you get. To avoid, put it outside the function, in the code that you do not show here.

Answer (score 2):

Since your function is recursive, each call will print out its own time.  If you want to know how much time the function took, I would suggest wrapping the main call to `fib` in a time statement, rather than putting the timing in the actual function code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of placing the code which calculates the time inside the `fib()` function, place it outside the function, like so:

```
import time

def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        answer = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
        return answer

#Place it all here

start_time = time.time()
fib(90) #Or some other number
end_time = time.time()
total_time = end_time - start_time

print(total_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

You use my timing program that I wrote.

```
#!python3

import timeit
from os import system
system('cls')
# %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %

# times the code 100 times
runs = 100
totalTime = 0.0; average = 0.0
testTimes = []

for i in range(runs):
    startTimer = timeit.default_timer()
    # %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %
    # >>>>> code to be tested goes here <<<<<
    def fib(n):
        if n <= 1:
            return 1
        else:
            answer = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
            return answer

    r = fib(26)
    print('fib result is:', r)
    # %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %
    endTimer = timeit.default_timer()

    timeInterval = endTimer - startTimer
    testTimes.append(timeInterval)
    totalTime += timeInterval
    print('\n', '{} {:.4f} {}'.format("This run's time is", timeInterval,
    'seconds' + '\n'))

# print the results
print('{} {:.4f} {}'.format('   Total time:', totalTime, 'seconds'))
print('{} {:.4f} {}'.format('Shortest time:', min(testTimes), 'seconds'))
print('{} {:.4f} {}'.format(' Longest time:', max(testTimes), 'seconds'))
print('{} {:.4f} {}'.format(' Average time:', (totalTime / runs), 'seconds'))
```

Answer (score 1):

As others noted, to time a recursive function,  place the timings around the call to the function,  not in the function.   Here some additional code to time computing the first 30 number of the sequence.

```
import time
import numpy as np

def fib(n):

    if n <= 1:
        answer = 1

    else: 
        answer = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

    return answer

for i in np.arange(1,30):

    start = time.time()
    f = fib(i)
    end = time.time()
    total = end - start

    print(i, fib(i), total)
```